# How can I improve the application administrator's encryption keys security inside database

Tags: encryption, passwords, web-application, privacy, asymmetric

I am interested in the issue of establishing the security of data of users of a web application in the event of a database leak.

It was decided to use the following encryption chain:

1. *User data* is encrypted with a *user symmetric key* (AES)
2. The *user symmetric key* is encrypted with the *user's RSA public key*
3. The *user's private RSA key* is encrypted with a *key derived from the user's password* (PBKDF2)

This approach is described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529582/how-to-store-private-encrypted-user-data-in-the-database-but-make-them-availabl

Our system provides a **superuser** who can view the data of all users, as well as help them recover access to the account in case of a password loss. For this, the *user's RSA private keys* must also be encrypted using some additional key that is available to this **superuser**.
The protection of a cryptographic system is determined by the security of its weakest link, and therefore the security of this entire encryption system is reduced to the cryptographic strength of the **superuser's** password (and from what I've read, one PBKDF2 key can be brute-forced relatively easily, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16279280/7646189)

The question is how, without removing the concept of superuser, to strengthen the security of the **superuser's** encryption keys in the database.

The first thing that comes to my mind is for the administrator to use yet another *encryption key* **INSTEAD** of a *password*. But I don't understand how it can be used in this scheme, and how the **superuser** should store this key then and present it to the database for deciphering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Compile the encryption key from data outside of the database

Database hacks are more common than application hacks, and application hacks are more common than full system hacks.  It is pretty common for your database to be stolen without your whole system being compromised.  In most cases, you can simply put a key into a separate config file kind of like WordPress does so that in case of a database dump, the key is outside of the scope of what is stolen.

If you want to take it a step further you can compile your key from system information.  So, let's say someone steals your whole application and database and puts it on their computer to reverse engineer, your PHP/ASP.NET whatever may in it's encryption method create your key each time it needs it by hashing some combination of system checks.  So maybe it is taking things like your MAC address, Computer name, IP, etc, concatenating them together, and then hashing them to create a key.

Since these system specs are static and unique (in theory), it means that your system will generate the same key every time on your system, but the moment you go to put the data on another system, it will generate a different key because your system specs have changed.  Thus nullifying the hacker's ability to read your data.

That said, you should be very cautious about when and where you implement this because it means that your data will forever be tied to the system it is on; so, if your server dies (or your cloud hosting provider changes something on you), then you risk being locked out of your own system.  So when you do this, you should write yourself a script for saving your compiled key, put in on a thumb drive or something like that, and then remove the script from your application.  This way you can manually unlock your system in the future if you need to.

On many systems, the potential for downtime or total data loose this could create is considered an unacceptable risk compared to the security advantages it provides; so, make sure with your project coordinator that the risk/reward here is worth it to them and/or your client for the project you are working on.

Comment: Thank you! I think it gave me an insight into how can I create such an encryption key on client.

Comment: I agree that the implementation of such a system is a great risk in itself. I think that even if we will come up with some sort of key tied to the user system, we will need a backup plan, like a securely stored USB drive with the same keys or something like that.

Comment: Sorry for the possible inconvenience, but I think that this does not deserve a question on its own.
There is one idea that circling in my head, about using the digital signature of some static string (say, string "password"), created with an RSA certificate private key. In this case, certificates can be managed and "backup-ed" more easily than concrete computer system info, and will still be secure, if the certificate private key is secure (say, on digital token).
Is there any way to "compromise" such a "password", knowing only static string and certificate public key?

Comment: Your application would need access to the system admin's password every time a user wants to log in in order to include it in the encryption method.  This means you'd need to store the admin password or a key derived from it somewhere accessible by the application making this just a variation of the first solution I proposed.  The easier solution is just to put the the key in a config file as per my 1st suggestion and skip the extra steps since it's the same difficulty for a hacker to break.

Comment: First of all, a big thank you for helping! 
Honestly, I can't fully agree with you on that point, because in the described scenario derived key will be stored in application memory. It's not far from storing keys in configuration file plaintext in terms of security, but at least it is harder than just steal file from the filesystem.
Please, correct me if I'm mistaken. I think that I have not clarified that this derivation will happen only in runtime.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you.  So let me get this straight: you want an admin, when booting up the server to put in his password to generate a hash in memory to use as a key?  I could see that being better than using system specs while following the same principle.  The only possible limitation I can think of is that the languages designed around web development like PHP intentionally limit variable scopes to pages and sessions to keep one person's session from hijacking another... so I don't know if there is a good way to implement this or not.

Comment: Yes, we have a misunderstanding. Let me reiterate.
There will be web app users, whose data will be encrypted in the database using keys, derived from their passwords.
There will also be a system admin, who can access user data in desktop app. To give him access to users' data I need to encrypt user keys with the administrator's one.
Admin key cannot be derived from a password, because it can be too easy to brute force, and get access to all data at once.
Instead, I plan to create an RSA signature with the admin's personal RSA certificate. This key will be stored in application memory.

Comment: Even RSA Certificates normally exist as files on your computer that can be stolen.  Sounds like what you may want to use is a dongle.  It's a good compromise between the two.  Basically it is a thumb drive that contains an encryption key that you need to plug into a computer to make a program work.  For best security, you can make the dongle needed to start up your application (load your key into memory), and then you unplug it before you open up access to the internet.